# Create 3D-Terrain from Script with BlenderGIS

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to write an external script that creates a 3D terrain using BlenderGIS. Unfortunately, I have not found any direct documentation on this.

- Blender Version: 3.4.1
- Python Version: 3.10.8
- BlenderGIS Version: 2.2.8

I already have a workflow in BlenderGUI that leads to the desired result:

1. create basemap, OSM with Mapnik.
2. press <kbd>G</kbd> key, enter coordinates, set zoom level
3. press <kbd>E</kbd> key to export the map
4. load SRTM data (SRTM 30M) and link it to the map.

I found the tutorial via the GIT repo: https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/wiki/Quick-start

My current code looks like this:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'
bpy.ops.view3d.map_start(src='OSM', lay='MAPNIK', query='Berlin', zoom=17)
```

But when I run it, only the "standard" map is displayed. Neither the reference of the query works, nor the zoom level.
Does anyone know a solution to my problem or already have a working code?